# PatternSequence two consecutive numbers that are negatives of each other

Tags: pattern-matching

trying to do a pattern matching on a list, I want to find the two members that are negatives of each other, i.e.:

```
{0.,1.5,-1.5,4.2}
```

I tried:

```
listOfNumbers/. {x___, PatternSequence[z__, -z__], y___} :> {z}
```

And every similar case, but I am missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: Might there be several pairs of a, -a?

Comment: No, there is only one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Position[MovingAverage[mylist, 2], 0.]
```

Example:

```
mylist = {4, 6.8, 7.3, -7.3, 14, 22, π};

Position[MovingAverage[mylist, 2], 0.]
```

{{3}}

You can then select from mylist element 3 (and subsequent one).

Or:

```
mylist[[Position[MovingAverage[mylist, 2], 0][[1]]]]
```

{7}

It even works with functions that must be evaluated:

```
mylist = {4, 6.8, -2, 
   Limit[4 x^2/(2 x^2 + 1), x -> \[Infinity]], -7.3, 14, 22, π};
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Is there a simple way to extend this to the case when the two elements are last and first? I know I can append the first element to thee end of the list before doing this, but if there is a simpler way, let me know, please.

Comment: I would simply append the first element onto the end of the list.  So... is my answer acceptable (with a green check or up-vote)?

Comment: Yep, just accepted it. The only change I needed to do was 0. instead of 0 as my list contains floats.

Answer (score 5):

There are much more efficient ways to do this simple task vs pattern matching, e.g.:

```
adjacentOpSign=Pick[Range@Length@#, Unitize[# + RotateLeft@#], 0] &;

adjacentOpSign@{4, 6.8, 7.3, -7.3, 14, 22, π}
```

> {3}

This will be orders of magnitude faster for large lists, and automatically accounts for your cyclic (first and last meet criteria) needs...

Answer (score 4):

using patterns:

```
{0., 1.5, -1.5, 4.2} /. {___, PatternSequence[a_, b_] /; b == -a, ___} :> a
```

> 1.5

or to deal with floating point issues you might want this:

```
{0., 1.5, -1.5, 4.2} /. {___, PatternSequence[a_, b_] /; Chop[a+b]==0, ___} :> a
```